# Common Jars are not loaded in JBoss

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I want to add a common jar into JBoss 7.1.

I created a directory like this
*../jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/modules/writer/writer/main*

Inside the main directory I created module.xml. Here is what inside module.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="writer.writer">
    <resources> 
        <resource-root path="writer.jar"/> 
    </resources>
</module>
```

Then standalone.xml which is in *../jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/configuration*
I wrote like this

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1">         
        <module name="writer.writer" />         
</subsystem>
```

But JBoss can't load this and, jboss starting is failed.

Please let me know where is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have placed your jar under  `../jboss_home_dir/modules/writer/writer/main` and your module.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="writer.writer">
<resources> 
    <resource-root path="writer.jar"/> 
</resources>
</module>
```

Now you can refer to your module either as a global module or use jboss-deployment-structure.xml

To Use as a Global Module(which i assume is what you are trying to achieve):
Define your standalone.xml as below under subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0":

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" >            
  <global-modules>
   <module name="writer.writer" slot="main" />            
  </global-modules> 
</subsystem>
```

Alternatively use JBoss specific deployment descriptor jboss-deployment-structure.xml that can be used to control class loading. It should be placed in the top level deployment, in META-INF (or WEB-INF for web deployments).

Below sample jboss-deployment-structure.xml where you can control each of the sub deplyment class loading providing much flexibility.

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <sub-deployment name="mywarfile.war">
    <dependencies>
        <module name="writer.writer" />
    </dependencies>
  </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```